# Does paypal payment gateway sends otp using credit card payment?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I have integrated paypal payment gateway in my laravel project and I've used the live paypal account.
When I try to make payment by through credit card then I did not receive OPT by phone number although it was requested before payment.

What may the issue?